# function as parameter with generic object return type in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have a function defined as

```
final Function<Future<PageableModel<T>>>(String?) elementBuilder;
```

The compiler shows a compile error at "Future": `Expected to find '>'.`
Is it possible in Dart to define a generic object as the return type of a function defined as variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid syntax. You probably meant:

```
final Future<PageableModel<T>> Function(String?) elementBuilder;
```

Comment: @Donatic How is that awkward syntax?  Function return types in Dart normally go to the left of the function declaration.  It's also not any longer than what you originally tried.